# how to combine magnifying glass effect and lightbox together on an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to apply magnifying glass and lightbox both on an image so when a user hovers on an image the glass effect will appear and when he clicks the lightbox will appear. But in my case the lightbox stopped working when I actived the magnifying glass. So when I remove the glass CSS lightbox worked normally.

```js
/*!
 * Lightbox v2.10.0
 * by Lokesh Dhakar
 *
 * More info:
 * http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
 *
 * Copyright 2007, 2018 Lokesh Dhakar
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/LICENSE
 *
 * @preserve
 */
! function(a, b) {
  "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], b) : "object" == typeof exports ? module.exports = b(require("jquery")) : a.lightbox = b(a.jQuery)
}(this, function(a) {
  function b(b) {
    this.album = [], this.currentImageIndex = void 0, this.init(), this.options = a.extend({}, this.constructor.defaults), this.option(b)
  }
  return b.defaults = {
    albumLabel: "Image %1 of %2",
    alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices: !1,
    fadeDuration: 600,
    fitImagesInViewport: !0,
    imageFadeDuration: 600,
    positionFromTop: 50,
    resizeDuration: 700,
    showImageNumberLabel: !0,
    wrapAround: !1,
    disableScrolling: !1,
    sanitizeTitle: !1
  }, b.prototype.option = function(b) {
    a.extend(this.options, b)
  }, b.prototype.imageCountLabel = function(a, b) {
    return this.options.albumLabel.replace(/%1/g, a).replace(/%2/g, b)
  }, b.prototype.init = function() {
    var b = this;
    a(document).ready(function() {
      b.enable(), b.build()
    })
  }, b.prototype.enable = function() {
    var b = this;
    a("body").on("click", "a[rel^=lightbox], area[rel^=lightbox], a[data-lightbox], area[data-lightbox]", function(c) {
      return b.start(a(c.currentTarget)), !1
    })
  }, b.prototype.build = function() {
    if (!(a("#lightbox").length > 0)) {
      var b = this;
      a('<div id="lightboxOverlay" class="lightboxOverlay"></div><div id="lightbox" class="lightbox"><div class="lb-outerContainer"><div class="lb-container"><img class="lb-image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" /><div class="lb-nav"><a class="lb-prev" href="" ></a><a class="lb-next" href="" ></a></div><div class="lb-loader"><a class="lb-cancel"></a></div></div></div><div class="lb-dataContainer"><div class="lb-data"><div class="lb-details"><span class="lb-caption"></span><span class="lb-number"></span></div><div class="lb-closeContainer"><a class="lb-close"></a></div></div></div></div>').appendTo(a("body")), this.$lightbox = a("#lightbox"), this.$overlay = a("#lightboxOverlay"), this.$outerContainer = this.$lightbox.find(".lb-outerContainer"), this.$container = this.$lightbox.find(".lb-container"), this.$image = this.$lightbox.find(".lb-image"), this.$nav = this.$lightbox.find(".lb-nav"), this.containerPadding = {
        top: parseInt(this.$container.css("padding-top"), 10),
        right: parseInt(this.$container.css("padding-right"), 10),
        bottom: parseInt(this.$container.css("padding-bottom"), 10),
        left: parseInt(this.$container.css("padding-left"), 10)
      }, this.imageBorderWidth = {
        top: parseInt(this.$image.css("border-top-width"), 10),
        right: parseInt(this.$image.css("border-right-width"), 10),
        bottom: parseInt(this.$image.css("border-bottom-width"), 10),
        left: parseInt(this.$image.css("border-left-width"), 10)
      }, this.$overlay.hide().on("click", function() {
        return b.end(), !1
      }), this.$lightbox.hide().on("click", function(c) {
        return "lightbox" === a(c.target).attr("id") && b.end(), !1
      }), this.$outerContainer.on("click", function(c) {
        return "lightbox" === a(c.target).attr("id") && b.end(), !1
      }), this.$lightbox.find(".lb-prev").on("click", function() {
        return 0 === b.currentImageIndex ? b.changeImage(b.album.length - 1) : b.changeImage(b.currentImageIndex - 1), !1
      }), this.$lightbox.find(".lb-next").on("click", function() {
        return b.currentImageIndex === b.album.length - 1 ? b.changeImage(0) : b.changeImage(b.currentImageIndex + 1), !1
      }), this.$nav.on("mousedown", function(a) {
        3 === a.which && (b.$nav.css("pointer-events", "none"), b.$lightbox.one("contextmenu", function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            this.$nav.css("pointer-events", "auto")
          }.bind(b), 0)
        }))
      }), this.$lightbox.find(".lb-loader, .lb-close").on("click", function() {
        return b.end(), !1
      })
    }
  }, b.prototype.start = function(b) {
    function c(a) {
      d.album.push({
        alt: a.attr("data-alt"),
        link: a.attr("href"),
        title: a.attr("data-title") || a.attr("title")
      })
    }
    var d = this,
      e = a(window);
    e.on("resize", a.proxy(this.sizeOverlay, this)), a("select, object, embed").css({
      visibility: "hidden"
    }), this.sizeOverlay(), this.album = [];
    var f, g = 0,
      h = b.attr("data-lightbox");
    if (h) {
      f = a(b.prop("tagName") + '[data-lightbox="' + h + '"]');
      for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i = ++i) c(a(f[i])), f[i] === b[0] && (g = i)
    } else if ("lightbox" === b.attr("rel")) c(b);
    else {
      f = a(b.prop("tagName") + '[rel="' + b.attr("rel") + '"]');
      for (var j = 0; j < f.length; j = ++j) c(a(f[j])), f[j] === b[0] && (g = j)
    }
    var k = e.scrollTop() + this.options.positionFromTop,
      l = e.scrollLeft();
    this.$lightbox.css({
      top: k + "px",
      left: l + "px"
    }).fadeIn(this.options.fadeDuration), this.options.disableScrolling && a("html").addClass("lb-disable-scrolling"), this.changeImage(g)
  }, b.prototype.changeImage = function(b) {
    var c = this;
    this.disableKeyboardNav();
    var d = this.$lightbox.find(".lb-image");
    this.$overlay.fadeIn(this.options.fadeDuration), a(".lb-loader").fadeIn("slow"), this.$lightbox.find(".lb-image, .lb-nav, .lb-prev, .lb-next, .lb-dataContainer, .lb-numbers, .lb-caption").hide(), this.$outerContainer.addClass("animating");
    var e = new Image;
    e.onload = function() {
      var f, g, h, i, j, k;
      d.attr({
        alt: c.album[b].alt,
        src: c.album[b].link
      }), a(e), d.width(e.width), d.height(e.height), c.options.fitImagesInViewport && (k = a(window).width(), j = a(window).height(), i = k - c.containerPadding.left - c.containerPadding.right - c.imageBorderWidth.left - c.imageBorderWidth.right - 20, h = j - c.containerPadding.top - c.containerPadding.bottom - c.imageBorderWidth.top - c.imageBorderWidth.bottom - 120, c.options.maxWidth && c.options.maxWidth < i && (i = c.options.maxWidth), c.options.maxHeight && c.options.maxHeight < i && (h = c.options.maxHeight), (e.width > i || e.height > h) && (e.width / i > e.height / h ? (g = i, f = parseInt(e.height / (e.width / g), 10), d.width(g), d.height(f)) : (f = h, g = parseInt(e.width / (e.height / f), 10), d.width(g), d.height(f)))), c.sizeContainer(d.width(), d.height())
    }, e.src = this.album[b].link, this.currentImageIndex = b
  }, b.prototype.sizeOverlay = function() {
    this.$overlay.width(a(document).width()).height(a(document).height())
  }, b.prototype.sizeContainer = function(a, b) {
    function c() {
      d.$lightbox.find(".lb-dataContainer").width(g), d.$lightbox.find(".lb-prevLink").height(h), d.$lightbox.find(".lb-nextLink").height(h), d.showImage()
    }
    var d = this,
      e = this.$outerContainer.outerWidth(),
      f = this.$outerContainer.outerHeight(),
      g = a + this.containerPadding.left + this.containerPadding.right + this.imageBorderWidth.left + this.imageBorderWidth.right,
      h = b + this.containerPadding.top + this.containerPadding.bottom + this.imageBorderWidth.top + this.imageBorderWidth.bottom;
    e !== g || f !== h ? this.$outerContainer.animate({
      width: g,
      height: h
    }, this.options.resizeDuration, "swing", function() {
      c()
    }) : c()
  }, b.prototype.showImage = function() {
    this.$lightbox.find(".lb-loader").stop(!0).hide(), this.$lightbox.find(".lb-image").fadeIn(this.options.imageFadeDuration), this.updateNav(), this.updateDetails(), this.preloadNeighboringImages(), this.enableKeyboardNav()
  }, b.prototype.updateNav = function() {
    var a = !1;
    try {
      document.createEvent("TouchEvent"), a = !!this.options.alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices
    } catch (a) {}
    this.$lightbox.find(".lb-nav").show(), this.album.length > 1 && (this.options.wrapAround ? (a && this.$lightbox.find(".lb-prev, .lb-next").css("opacity", "1"), this.$lightbox.find(".lb-prev, .lb-next").show()) : (this.currentImageIndex > 0 && (this.$lightbox.find(".lb-prev").show(), a && this.$lightbox.find(".lb-prev").css("opacity", "1")), this.currentImageIndex < this.album.length - 1 && (this.$lightbox.find(".lb-next").show(), a && this.$lightbox.find(".lb-next").css("opacity", "1"))))
  }, b.prototype.updateDetails = function() {
    var b = this;
    if (void 0 !== this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title && "" !== this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title) {
      var c = this.$lightbox.find(".lb-caption");
      this.options.sanitizeTitle ? c.text(this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title) : c.html(this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title), c.fadeIn("fast").find("a").on("click", function(b) {
        void 0 !== a(this).attr("target") ? window.open(a(this).attr("href"), a(this).attr("target")) : location.href = a(this).attr("href")
      })
    }
    if (this.album.length > 1 && this.options.showImageNumberLabel) {
      var d = this.imageCountLabel(this.currentImageIndex + 1, this.album.length);
      this.$lightbox.find(".lb-number").text(d).fadeIn("fast")
    } else this.$lightbox.find(".lb-number").hide();
    this.$outerContainer.removeClass("animating"), this.$lightbox.find(".lb-dataContainer").fadeIn(this.options.resizeDuration, function() {
      return b.sizeOverlay()
    })
  }, b.prototype.preloadNeighboringImages = function() {
    if (this.album.length > this.currentImageIndex + 1) {
      (new Image).src = this.album[this.currentImageIndex + 1].link
    }
    if (this.currentImageIndex > 0) {
      (new Image).src = this.album[this.currentImageIndex - 1].link
    }
  }, b.prototype.enableKeyboardNav = function() {
    a(document).on("keyup.keyboard", a.proxy(this.keyboardAction, this))
  }, b.prototype.disableKeyboardNav = function() {
    a(document).off(".keyboard")
  }, b.prototype.keyboardAction = function(a) {
    var b = a.keyCode,
      c = String.fromCharCode(b).toLowerCase();
    27 === b || c.match(/x|o|c/) ? this.end() : "p" === c || 37 === b ? 0 !== this.currentImageIndex ? this.changeImage(this.currentImageIndex - 1) : this.options.wrapAround && this.album.length > 1 && this.changeImage(this.album.length - 1) : "n" !== c && 39 !== b || (this.currentImageIndex !== this.album.length - 1 ? this.changeImage(this.currentImageIndex + 1) : this.options.wrapAround && this.album.length > 1 && this.changeImage(0))
  }, b.prototype.end = function() {
    this.disableKeyboardNav(), a(window).off("resize", this.sizeOverlay), this.$lightbox.fadeOut(this.options.fadeDuration), this.$overlay.fadeOut(this.options.fadeDuration), a("select, object, embed").css({
      visibility: "visible"
    }), this.options.disableScrolling && a("html").removeClass("lb-disable-scrolling")
  }, new b
});
//# sourceMappingURL=lightbox.min.map


//magnyfing glass


$(function() {

  var native_width = 0;
  var native_height = 0;
  var mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };
  var magnify;
  var cur_img;

  var ui = {
    magniflier: $('.magniflier')
  };

  // Add the magnifying glass
  if (ui.magniflier.length) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'glass');
    ui.glass = $(div);

    $('body').append(div);
  }


  // All the magnifying will happen on "mousemove"

  var mouseMove = function(e) {
    var $el = $(this);

    // Container offset relative to document
    var magnify_offset = cur_img.offset();

    // Mouse position relative to container
    // pageX/pageY - container's offsetLeft/offetTop
    mouse.x = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;

    // The Magnifying glass should only show up when the mouse is inside
    // It is important to note that attaching mouseout and then hiding
    // the glass wont work cuz mouse will never be out due to the glass
    // being inside the parent and having a higher z-index (positioned above)
    if (
      mouse.x < cur_img.width() &&
      mouse.y < cur_img.height() &&
      mouse.x > 0 &&
      mouse.y > 0
    ) {

      magnify(e);
    } else {
      ui.glass.fadeOut(100);
    }

    return;
  };

  var magnify = function(e) {

    // The background position of div.glass will be
    // changed according to the position
    // of the mouse over the img.magniflier
    //
    // So we will get the ratio of the pixel
    // under the mouse with respect
    // to the image and use that to position the
    // large image inside the magnifying glass

    var rx = Math.round(mouse.x / cur_img.width() * native_width - ui.glass.width() / 2) * -1;
    var ry = Math.round(mouse.y / cur_img.height() * native_height - ui.glass.height() / 2) * -1;
    var bg_pos = rx + "px " + ry + "px";

    // Calculate pos for magnifying glass
    //
    // Easy Logic: Deduct half of width/height
    // from mouse pos.

    // var glass_left = mouse.x - ui.glass.width() / 2;
    // var glass_top  = mouse.y - ui.glass.height() / 2;
    var glass_left = e.pageX - ui.glass.width() / 2;
    var glass_top = e.pageY - ui.glass.height() / 2;
    //console.log(glass_left, glass_top, bg_pos)
    // Now, if you hover on the image, you should
    // see the magnifying glass in action
    ui.glass.css({
      left: glass_left,
      top: glass_top,
      backgroundPosition: bg_pos
    });

    return;
  };

  $('.magniflier').on('mousemove', function() {
    ui.glass.fadeIn(200);

    cur_img = $(this);

    var large_img_loaded = cur_img.data('large-img-loaded');
    var src = cur_img.data('large') || cur_img.attr('src');

    // Set large-img-loaded to true
    // cur_img.data('large-img-loaded', true)

    if (src) {
      ui.glass.css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + src + ')',
        'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'
      });
    }

    // When the user hovers on the image, the script will first calculate
    // the native dimensions if they don't exist. Only after the native dimensions
    // are available, the script will show the zoomed version.
    //if(!native_width && !native_height) {

    if (!cur_img.data('native_width')) {
      // This will create a new image object with the same image as that in .small
      // We cannot directly get the dimensions from .small because of the 
      // width specified to 200px in the html. To get the actual dimensions we have
      // created this image object.
      var image_object = new Image();

      image_object.onload = function() {
        // This code is wrapped in the .load function which is important.
        // width and height of the object would return 0 if accessed before 
        // the image gets loaded.
        native_width = image_object.width;
        native_height = image_object.height;

        cur_img.data('native_width', native_width);
        cur_img.data('native_height', native_height);

        //console.log(native_width, native_height);

        mouseMove.apply(this, arguments);

        ui.glass.on('mousemove', mouseMove);
      };


      image_object.src = src;

      return;
    } else {

      native_width = cur_img.data('native_width');
      native_height = cur_img.data('native_height');
    }
    //}
    //console.log(native_width, native_height);

    mouseMove.apply(this, arguments);

    ui.glass.on('mousemove', mouseMove);
  });

  ui.glass.on('mouseout', function() {
    ui.glass.off('mousemove', mouseMove);
  });

});
```

```css
html.lb-disable-scrolling {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Position fixed required for iOS. Just putting overflow: hidden; on the body is not enough. */
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.lightboxOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: black;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
}

.lightbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.lightbox .lb-image {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
  max-height: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* Image border */
  border: 4px solid white;
}

.lightbox a img {
  border: none;
}

.lb-outerContainer {
  position: relative;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* Background color behind image.
     This is visible during transitions. */
  background-color: white;
}

.lb-outerContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lb-loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  left: 0;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

.lb-cancel {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(../assets/imgs/lightbox/loading.gif) no-repeat;
}

.lb-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.lb-container>.nav {
  left: 0;
}

.lb-nav a {
  outline: none;
  background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==');
}

.lb-prev,
.lb-next {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev {
  width: 34%;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  background: url(../assets/imgs/lightbox/prev.png) left 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-next {
  width: 64%;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  background: url(../assets/imgs/lightbox/next.png) right 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-next:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.lb-dataContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.lb-dataContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lb-data {
  padding: 0 4px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.lb-data .lb-details {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}

.lb-data .lb-caption {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.lb-data .lb-caption a {
  color: #4ae;
}

.lb-data .lb-number {
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #999999;
}

.lb-data .lb-close {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(../assets/imgs/lightbox/close.png) top right no-repeat;
  text-align: right;
  outline: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.lb-data .lb-close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}


/* IF you remove this, lightbox will work but not the magnyfing glass */

.glass {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: crosshair;
  /* Multiple box shadows to achieve the glass effect */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), 0 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  /* hide the glass by default */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--START BOOK PREVIEW-->
<div class="book-preview px-5 py-5 container img-magnifier-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 book">
      <a href="https://subsolardesigns.com/odrin/demo1/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2017/08/cover_taurus-468x700.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">
        <img src="https://subsolardesigns.com/odrin/demo1/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2017/08/cover_taurus-468x700.png" alt="Book" class="img-fluid magniflier" id="book-glass" alt="Responsive image">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are not clicking the image, but the `.glass` dom node. You need to handle the click event on the `.glass` element and then call click on the image, in order for the lightbox plugin to do what it expects to do. Add the code below to you javascript to redirect the click event to your image tag.

```
ui.glass.on('click', function() {
  cur_img.click();
});
```